Are the ranks of the following matrices given by these simple expressions?
The question itself is formulated in the title, so below I specify the matrices and expressions mentioned there. In case if this is something known or can be easily deduced from something known, this question should be treated as a reference request. Anyway, any insights on the problem would be greatly appreciated.
Let $N$ be a positive integer and $S(N)$ be the symmetric group on $N$ letters. Below we consider two rectangular matrices $A_N$ and $B_N$ of size $N^2\times N!$ whose rows are indexed by pairs of integers from $1$ to $N$ and columns are indexed by the permutations from $S(N)$. The entries of the first matrix $A_N$ are either $0$ or $1$, and the entries of the second matrix could be also $-1$.
The first matrix is given by
$$
(A_N)_{(i,j),w}=\begin{cases}
1,\ \text{if}\ w(i)=j,\\[5pt]
0,\ \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$
So, the entry corresponding to the pair $(i,j)$ and the permutation $w$ is $1$, if $w(i)=j$, and zero otherwise. For instance,

In this example we use the one row notation for permutations.
Now we can compute ranks of matrices $\{A_N\}_{N\geq 1}$ and obtain a sequence of integer numbers.

Conjecture 1: One has $\operatorname{rk}(A_N)=(N-1)^2+1$

Let's consider a more symmetric version of the problem. Namely, let's define the second matrix $B_N$ as follows
$$
(B_N)_{(i,j),w}=\begin{cases}
1,\ \text{if}\ w(i)=j,\ \text{and}\ w(j)\neq i,\\[5pt]
-1,\ \text{if}\ w(j)=i,\ \text{and}\ w(i)\neq j,\\[5pt]
0,\ \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$

Conjecture 2: One has $\operatorname{rk}(B_N)=\cfrac{(N-2)(N-1)}{2}$

I have verified both conjectures for $N=1,\ldots,8$.
However, OEIS suggests other sequences coinciding with these up to the 8-th order. Among all suitable sequences, $(N-1)^2+1$ and $\cfrac{(N-2)(N-1)}{2}$ appear to be the simplest.
Any insights into proving or disproving these conjectures would be greatly appreciated, as well as any links to related problems.

The rank of $A_N$ is the dimension of its column space, but its column space is the span of all permutation matrices (vectorized as vectors of length $N^2$). The latter span is known to have dimension $\left(N-1\right)^2 + 1$ (see, e.g., https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/70569/span-of-permutation-matrices ).

Likewise, the rank of $B_N$ is the dimension of the span of the matrices $P - P^T$, where $P$ ranges over the permutation matrices. Knowing a basis of the span of all permutation matrices, you can easily find a basis of the new span as well.

@darijgrinberg Thank you!
